# Exclude html file types from FAST SEARCH results - SharePoint

Tags: performance, search, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to exclude *.html  files from Fast Search results. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Meta robot tags in the html pages. Think SharePoint Fast should then exclude them.

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/exclude-web-pages-from-search-engines-using-meta-r.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: What I mean is when i type *.html i dont want to see any .html file.It gives 100 items in search results for *.html. so therefore adding meta robot tag is not easy

Comment: Can any body share some ideas on how to stop Fast Search result returning *.html pages